# Global Entry interview — Moved to a new place since application, but unoffically

Tags: global-entry

I live in the SF Bay Area and signed up for CBP [Global Entry](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry) several months ago. My interview is tonight.

Since I submitted, I have moved to a new address, but not officially and possibly not for long. I had a friend who wanted to live in the area I was living in for 3 months, and a second friend who owns a house and was willing to give me discounted rent, so we worked out a housing swap. The first friend moved into my place (but I'm still on the lease) and I moved into my second friends place, no lease was signed since he owns it.

Once my first friend moves out of my place at the end of the lease, I might move back. I'm not sure yet.

Anyway

**Do I need to let them know about my new address? If so, do I need to bring documentation to prove that? For the new address or for the one I "officially" live at, or both?**

This is complicated by the fact that I was planning to go straight to the interview from work, and I do not have any documentation on me to prove my address. Can I tell them my new address and submit proof later?

Or do I need to drive all the way home to get proof of address (1hr drive) then all the way back to the airport (30 min) as oppose to just sticking around after work like I planned? I'd really rather not do that.

EDIT: Just a thought. I say it is unofficial since I'm just staying with a friend, but I did let the DMV and my Bank know of my new address, so perhaps that makes it official.

EDIT2: Since my bank has my new address I can just stop by a bank after work and request a print out containing my address. I plan to do that. Will update here after interview though!

UPDATE:
Interview went well. They accepted my printed out bank statement as a proof of address. I thankfully remembered to bring my passport to work because I needed that too. Also needed driver's license but I always have that. Interview was super simple. Just asked what countries I had been to and if I had upcoming travel plans, and some basic questions on if I had any criminal history.

Comment: Will you be able to collect mail from your old address?

Comment: Yes, I just need to check with old roomates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [USCBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1775/~/what-if-my-status-changes-while-i-am-waiting-for-my-global-entry-interview%3F):

> If any information in your application has changed or needs to be
>   updated after you have certified your application and paid the
>   processing fee, you must wait until you attend your scheduled
>   interview to update the information with the Global Enrollment Center.
>   Please be sure to bring supporting documentation with you to your
>   interview about the requested changes....
>
> ....This may also include address changes and other pertinent
>   information that would be included on your Global Entry Application.

What I am reading is that you will need to bring documentation supporting the change.

However, in my own experience for Global Entry, the background check happens before you're invited for an interview. I was approved on the spot for Global Entry right after my interview. Therefore, **in my opinion** if you don't tell them that you changed addresses, and then change it your GOES account after you get your card, that's an option. But again, that's just **my opinion** - never hurts to be cautious with these things. Do keep in mind that your card will be mailed to the address you have on your application.

Comment: Thanks.

It occurred to be I could easily obtain a proof of address from my bank by asking for a printed out statement, so I did that.